# JSON Lint output lead in endless circle

Tags: json

I have my training data in a `JSON` file and must have accidentally inserted a charecter where I shouldn't have. B.c when I try to load my `JSON` file I get the error:

```
Can't parse json file "data/converted_data.json"

SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 51360
```

Given this is data in JSON format how to I find position `51360`?

Thanks to a helpful comment I ran JSON Lint on the data resulting in:

```
Error: Parse error on line 53947:
...]      }    ]  }}
-------------------^
Expecting ',', ']', got '}'
```

If I remove the `}` I get:

```
Error: Parse error on line 53947:
...]      }    ]  }
-------------------^
Expecting ',', ']', got 'EOF'
```

And if I replace it with a `]` I get

```
...      }    ]  }]
-------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', got 'EOF'
```

Seems impossible to break out of, any idea what might be causing them.

Comment: sounds like you have an unescaped c in your JSON. Position 51360 is a long way into the file so you probably can't post the whole thing so maybe upload to www.jsonlint.com

Comment: edited question to add json lint output, it raised more questions

Comment: figured out I accidentally deleted a line which was causing the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Json Lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonlint) will go through and validate your JSON code locally. This pointed me to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a code editor like Atom, you can open the file with it and go to a specific line:column by clicking the cursor position info on the bottom of the window.

[image]

NOTE: For me, there's a bug where I have to go to another tab (after jumping into the specific column) and come back to it to see the cursor.

Hope that helps.